# XSLT transform file blank output

Tags: xml, xslt, saml

I need to create a XSLT file to transform an incoming SAML file to XML. But my transform file is not creating any output and I'm not sure why? When I try to plug the following into an online translator tool, and get an error about "error evaluating template at line 5 in module"?

**Incoming SAML:**

```
<root>
<saml:Attribute Name="State" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue>OR</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="Pilot_Item" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue>Skateboard</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="UserType" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue>Broker</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="Pilot_Item" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue>HandGlider</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="State" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue>CA</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
</root>
```

**XSLT Transform file:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<xsl:template match="/">
        <USERINFO>
            <xsl:for-each select="//saml:Attribute[@Name='State']/saml:AttributeValue">
                <xsl:element name="field">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">State</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="//saml:Attribute[@Name='Pilot_Item']/saml:AttributeValue">
                <xsl:element name="field">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">Custom1</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="//saml:Attribute[@Name='UserType']/saml:AttributeValue">
                <xsl:element name="field">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">Group</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </USERINFO>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required output:**

```
<UserInfo>
    <Custom1>Skateboard,HandGlider</Custom1>
    <State>CA,OR</State>
    <Group>Broker</Group>
</UserInfo>
```

Comment: Your input is not well-formed: the namespace prefix `saml` is not defined.

Comment: Also, you should tell us whether you are able to use XSLT 2.0 or whether you are constrained to XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the failure to produce any output is because of namespace declarations. The fact that you've shown the input file without its namespace declarations probably indicates that you haven't realised how important these are when tackling problems like this.

Apart from that your code looks OK but terribly verbose. Here's a shorter version:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <USERINFO>
    <field name="State" 
           value="{string-join(//saml:Attribute[@Name='State']/saml:AttributeValue, ',')}"/>
    <field name="Custom1" 
           value="{string-join(//saml:Attribute[@Name='Pilot_Item']/saml:AttributeValue, ',')}"/>
    <field name="Group" 
           value="{string-join(//saml:Attribute[@Name='UserType']/saml:AttributeValue, ',')}"/>
  </USERINFO>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your [solution](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifqi)

the saml namespace was not defined in source xml but it was defined in your xslt.